# Doubt regarding electric current

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, velocity, conductors

If we consider a simple dc circuit with just a resistor, we notice that V is constant and so is the length through which current is flowing, hence the electric field is constant. So why does drift velocity also remain constant shouldn't it be increasing linearly?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think drift velocity should be increasingly linearly ? In a resistive material the drift velocity $u$ is proportional to the electric field $E$, so if $E$ is constant so is $u$ (ignoring any transient state when the current is first turned on). See the Wikipedia article on [drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity) for further details.

Comment: case 1. no electric field: net drift velocity is 0. case 2. there is an external and constant electric field and electrons move with net constant acceleration. Can't we consider the question to be a superposition of the above two cases?(since there is no motion of positive charges) and so wouldn't the electrons be accelarating?

Comment: @Jonathan You are picturing the electrons as if they were moving in a vacuum, which has zero resistivity. But in fact the electrons are moving in a wire, which will have a non-zero resistivity. The resistivity of the wire (which is due to a combination of impurities in the metallic lattice and thermal vibrations of its atoms) opposes the electrons' motion and the end results is that the electrons have a maximum drift velocity which has a finite value.

Comment: So our understanding that ratio of drift velocity to electric field is constant is experimental?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes. It is a consequence of Ohm's Law, which is an empirical law.